# Example of entire that is not injective and its derivative is not identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an example where $f$ is entire that is not injective and satisfies $f'\neq 0$ on $\mathbb{C}$?

Moreover, how to show the following claim?

> Suppose $\Omega$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ and is convex. Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. If $\Im f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in \Omega$, then $f$ must be injective on $\Omega$.

When I look at the following exercise which I already have done, I think I could use this to prove the claim above, but I am not sure how exactly:

> Let $G$ open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $a\in G$. Assume $f$ holomorphic satisfying that $f'(a)\neq 0$. Prove that there exists $r>0$, such that $|f'(z)-f'(a)|<|f'(a)|$ for $z\in B(a,r)\subseteq G$. Show next that
> $$
> |\int_{0}^{1}f'(tz_2+(1-t)z_1)dt-f'(a)|\leq |f'(a)|,\\
> f(z_1)-f(a_2)=(z_2-z_1)\int_{0}^{1}f'(tz_2+(1-t)z_1)dt
> $$
> for all $z_1,z_2\in B(a,r)$, and deduce that $f|_{B(a,r)}$ is one to one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think $e^z$ should be a good example of entire function that is not injective

Comment: @Caffeine Thanks for spotting it ... Edited

Comment: @Gabrielek That's very true! Thanks for giving an example

Comment: for point two use that $\Im f'$ has constant sign on the domain and then $\Im \int_{0}^{1}f'(tz_2+(1-t)z_1)dt=\int_{0}^{1}\Im f'(tz_2+(1-t)z_1)dt$ since $dt$ is real measure, so the integral cannot vanish

Comment: @Conrad How do you see that $\Im f$ does not change its sign?

Comment: its image is a connected set of reals (hence an interval) which doesn't contain zero...