# Is $g(z):=z\operatorname{Log}z-z$ injective in some set?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $g(z):=z\operatorname{Log}z-z$, where the logarithm is the principal logarithm. Clearly, this is injective in $\{\Im z>0\}$ by the previos [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4003231/example-of-entire-that-is-not-injective-and-its-derivative-is-not-identically-ze). The question is, is $g$ also injective in $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$?

Comment: It is not injective on $0<z<e$ but injective on $z\geq 1$. I think you can handle $\Im z<0$ via the Schwarz reflection principle. If it is real only for real $z$ then this should be enough to prove injectivity on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,1)$.

Comment: note that $g'(1)=0, g''(1) \ne 0$ so $g$ is $2:1$ in a neighborhood of $1$ and $g$ cannot be injective on any circle centered at $1$ of radius $0<r<1$

Comment: more generally if $J$ is a Jordan curve in $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ (and even in $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0)$, extending $g(0)=0$) which contains $1$ inside, we cannot have $g$ injective on $J$